# Option button_click to return text if true

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, userform

Me again,

In my userform I just added 2 optionbutton click (1 and 2). 
What I need is when you choose one of those buttons to get text in cell ( Option button 1 text I need in cell is Daily check and optionbutton 2 is weekly check).

I tried with this code but it gives me only false or true as return information.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.value = True Then
    Range("I2").value = "MONTHLY CHECK"
    Else
    Range("I2").value = "OPERATIONAL DAY"
    End If End sub
```

Then after choosing option button this I have Commmand button that would enter this data (daily check or weekly check) into cells in column I, every entry new row which works but as I said only with true or false information

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim sh As Worksheet, lastRow As Long
  Set sh = Sheets("Test")
  lastRow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    sh.Range("I" & lastRow).value = OptionButton1.value
    sh.Range("I" & lastRow).value = OptionButton2.value
Unload Me
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance on your help, as always.

Comment: Perhaps try `OptionButton.Caption` rather than `.Value`. The Value of an option button is either true of false (indicating if it's selected or not) whereas the caption is the text you can read assigned to that button.

Comment: @SamuelEverson I just chanfed .value to .caption and I managed to get return information I needed. Thanks a lot for this tip, appreciate it.

Comment: I've added an answer for the sake of having an answer (I couldn't find any other question/answers that addressed this!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment, the issue is you are assigning your `sh.Range` values with the `OptionButton.Value`.

Per the [OptionButton.Value property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.optionbutton.value);  *Determines or specifies whether the specified option button is selected...*

The `.Value` property returns *True/False* if the OptionButton is *Selected/Unselected* respectively.
**Note:** You can also change the state of the OptionButton to select/unselect it by setting the `.Value` property in your code.

The OptionButton.Caption property ([see here for label.caption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.label.caption) which outlines the same principal for an optionbutton caption) is the visible text to the user generally describing what the optionbutton is for or does.

So your code was returning *True/False* because you were using the `.Value` property - instead use the `.Caption` property to return the descriptive text assigned to that optionbutton.

### Example:

[image: Example userform with 1 option button]

This is a new UserForm with one OptionButton, both with default names.

`OptionButton1.Value` is `True`
**AND**
`OptionButton1.Caption` is `This is OptionButton1.`

If we were to unselect the optionbutton (say by executing some 'Reset' code) the `OptionButton1.Value` would then be `False` but the `OptionButton1.Caption` would remain `This is OptionButton1.`